# Why the cloth penetrates collision object?

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

I made a person and set cloth simulation to cloth. At first, simulation worked well, but after set running animation, it became not so good. As you can see, the cloth penetrates body object that I set collision. So please tell me how can I fix it.

blender ver:2.79b
[image]

[image]

**P.S.Thank you very much for comment.
I added some images.
The second one of three added pictures is cloth object and third one is collision object.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your physics settings.and wireframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Since there isn't a .blend file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file), it's going to be challenging for us to properly diagnose your solution, since we won't be able to reproduce your setup.

That being said, I can see one thing that might help. The "quality" counter that you show in your screenshots is at 1. When I simulate cloth, I often increase the quality steps. For example, in **Blender 2.82a**, if I make a plane and apply the cloth modifier, I usually use these quality steps:

[image]

I increased the **Cloth -> Quality Steps** from the default value of 5 to 10. Furthermore, I increased the **Collisions -> Quality** from the default value of 2 to 5, and turned on **Collisions -> Self-Collisions**. Since your screenshots show quality values of 1, you might want to significantly increase that number. I would recommend looking at some Blender 2.7x videos that use cloth, and pay close attention to the quality steps value that they use. For example, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjY2YXXIel8) seems to use values of 5 for the quality steps.

As an aside, consider using Blender 2.8. The more recent versions of Blender have significant improvements to the cloth simulator. For example, [consider this blog post](https://code.blender.org/2017/06/improvements-to-the-cloth-simulator/) or the release notes Wiki, which for example, [say that 2.83 has improvements with cloth collisions](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.83/Physics).

Comment: Thank you very much!